# Copy specific field from different websites to worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

I need a vbscript that could be used to copy an output from different webpages and copy it into excel sheet

Example:

Website like truecaller.Com which you can search for people by phone number. 
Each number represent by unique web address ex(www.truecaller.com/au/439965324)
I need to make an excel sheet that has two columns; the 1st one is the web address and the 2nd one 8s the related name

Comment: Show us what you have tried, and we can help you with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Excel VBA is not the best for web scraping but it can get the job done.
Firstly you'll need to make sure you download the latest Internet Explorer, or at least ensure you have version 9 or above.
Secondly, you'll have to enable some references on your macros (these are analogous to imports in languages like Java). To do this, open your VBA editor, and go to Tools > References. You'll want to tick **Microsoft Internet Controls** and **Microsoft HTML Object Library**.
[image]

Now you're good to go, the following code should work for you. Not being a member of true caller, I only see "-" in the name field, but I imagine it's different if you have an account. The script I've made simply pulls out the name, number and address. I'm sure you won't have a problem with looping through your desired URLs and then placing the grabbed data where you want them.

```
Sub Test()
'to refer to the running copy of Internet Explorer
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
'to refer to the HTML document returned
Dim html As HTMLDocument
'open Internet Explorer in memory, and go to website
Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = False
ie.navigate "www.truecaller.com/au/439965324"
'Wait until IE is done loading page
Do While ie.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
Application.StatusBar = "Trying to go to StackOverflow ..."
DoEvents
Loop
'show text of HTML document returned
Set html = ie.document
MsgBox html.DocumentElement.innerHTML
Dim element As IHTMLElement
Set element = html.getElementsByClassName("result__details")(0)
Dim Name As String
Dim Number As String
Dim Address As String
Name = element.Children(0).Children(1).innerText
Number = element.Children(1).Children(1).innerText
Address = element.Children(2).Children(1).innerText
MsgBox ("Name is " & Name & " with number " & Number & ". Address: " & Address)
'close down IE and reset status bar
Set ie = Nothing
Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

If you want to learn more about scraping with VBA then here's a good link:
http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s393/scraping-websites-vba.htm

Comment: thanks a lot quantum285 its very close to what i actually doing in my research 
but if you could help me more if i have a range of numbers (428260000 to 428269999)
how could put it into excel sheet in two columns number and name
sorry my knowledge in VBA is very limited
appreciate your help